# ¿Cómo redirigir desde el filter a una u otra pagina?

Tags: java, filtro

A ver he puesto un loginFilter en mi proyecto web java, y quiero redirigir al usuario al main.jsp  o a error.jps dependiendo de si esta logueado o no.
Entonces os explico el recorrido y lo que ocurre.

Desde login.jsp, en el action del formulario de inicio de sesión pone login(es el servlet), pero no va directo al servlet sino que antes de llegar al servlet, pasa por el filtro(cosa que me gustaría que fuese al revés, me facilitaría mucho las cosas). Indagando, he descubierto que en el filtro, todo el codigo que pones despues del chain.doFilter(request, response), se ejecuta despues de ir al servlet.
Es decir, del login.jsp llega al filtro en el filtro , cuando llega al chain.doFilter, para y se va al login.java, aqui hace lo que tiene que hacer y vuelve al filtro.
En el filtro ahora lo que hago es comprobar si hay user en la sesión(osea si esta logueado). y si no lo esta tiene que redirigir a error.jsp, si lo esta, lo manda al main.jsp.

El caso es que cuando intento hacer eso, me da la siguiente excepción:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: No puedo reenviar después de que la respuesta se haya llevado a cabo.**

**LoginFilter.class**

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
protected FilterConfig filterConfig;

   java.util.List revokeList; 


   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
   FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
       RequestDispatcher dd;




      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
      HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
      HttpSession session =((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
      chain.doFilter(request, response); 
      User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");                
      String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
      String urNo = "mani.jsp";





      UserBO uBO = new UserBO();

     if(url.equals("http://localhost:8080/com.calendar/login.jsp")||url.equals("http://localhost:8080/com.calendar/index.html")|| url.equals("http://localhost:8080/com.calendar/registro.jsp")) {


     }else {
         if(user != null) {

              if(uBO.recoveryWeb(user, urNo)) {//este metodo comprueva si el 
                                               //user tiene acceso a esa web                                                                  
              }else {                   
                  url = "login.jsp";                      
              }           

         }else {                 
             url = "index.html";                  
          }          
         dd=request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
         dd.forward(request, response);          
     }





   }




}
```

lo he llamado LoginFilter, pero no es un filtro especifico para el login, tengo que cambiarle el nombre.

Quiero que me sirva para todas las paginas de mi web. 
Necesito que pase primero por el servlet y en el servlet comprueba si existe el usuario o no, y ademas en tal caso añade el usuario a la sesión.
por lo tanto cuando llega al filter por primera vez la sesión es nula aun, por eso quería que primero se ejecutase el servlet y luego el filtro pero no he podido.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que te indica es debido a que estás haciendo dos redirecciones, una de ellas al hacer el `doFilter` y otra, al realizar el `forward`.
En el momento de realizar una redirección, debes realizar un `return` para que no continue la ejecución del método.

Por otro lado el planteamiento de bloquear por ruta no es correcto, mejor define a qué servlets se aplica el filtro para que no lo haga por esas que defines.

Yo lo enfocaría con algo así:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();

    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
    String urNo = "mani.jsp";

    if (user == null || !uBO.recoveryWeb(user, urNo)) {// este metodo comprueba si el user tiene acceso a esa web
        res.sendRedirect("/ruta/login");
        return;
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Observa el return justo después de hacer la redirección.

En la definición del filtro:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>url.tu.paquete.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>loginPage</param-name>
        <param-value>/login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>TuServletSecurizado</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>TuServletSecurizado</description>
    <display-name>TuServletSecurizado</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TuServletSecurizado</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>url.tu.paquete.TuServletSecurizado</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

El que no quieras securizar, por ejemplo *login.jsp* no le añadas el filtro.

Comment: pero es que si lo hago así, el user es null, es decir primero hay que ir al servlet y después al volver, ejecutarse el if.

Comment: ademas ese if no me sirve, porque  el metodo recoveryWeb, tengo que llamarlo si User no es null. osea, que si es null  hago una cosa y si no lo es hago otra, por eso es que tienen que ir en ifs distintos. Y otra cosa, no puedo usar el break, me da error me dice que no puedo usarlo fuera de un Switch.

Comment: es que el if tiene que ir despues del chain.doFilter, porque tiene que ejecutarse al volver del servlet. no entiendo que quieres decir cuando dices:   el planteamiento de bloquear por ruta no es correcto, mejor define a qué servlets se aplica el filtro para que no lo haga por esas que defines.  precisamente trato de bloquear el acceso a según que rutas si una persona no esta logueada o no tiene el rango adecuado.

Comment: Si lo hago como dices, el usuario va a ser null todo el rato, porque primero hay que ir al servlet a comprobar si el usuario existe, de ahi que ponga todo el codigo despues del chainDoFilter

Comment: otra cosa mas, dices "mejor define a qué servlets se aplica el filtro" no puedo hacer eso porque el objetivo es que si tu pones en el navegador la url por ejemplo miweb.com/main.jsp no te deje acceder y te reenvíe al login.  y cuando tu pones una url en el navegador, no estas llamando a ningún servlet

Comment: Hola, perdona, he modificado alguna cosa en el código. `break` no es, es `return` para que termine el código.
El filtro precisamente se encarga de comprobar que el usuario esté en la sesión, y si no lo está, redirija al login.

Comment: ya por eso digo, el que se encarga de meter el usuario en la sesión, es el servlet, por eso es que cuando intento hacer login, al llegar al filter el usuario es null porque el usuario no se ha metido en la sesión todavía, entonces yo lo que intentaba, era al llegar chainDofilter parar, me voy al servlet meto al user en la sesión y luego vuelvo al filter y compruebo.   Porque hasta que no voy al servlet el usuario va a ser siempre null.

Comment: Es como  si en una discoteca, tu compras la entra y hay un segurata que miras si tienes la entrada y a continuación otro que te pone la cuña,  pues el que mira si tienes la entrada es el servlet, y el que te pone la cuña es el filter, solo que cuando le doy al submit "iniciar sesión" se va directo a la cuña, por eso pongo todo ese codigo después del chainDofilter, para que eso se ejecute después de pasar por el servlet(después de que me revisen la entrada).

Comment: lo de la definición de filter me viene perfecto gracias y como veo lo del return voy a probar.

Comment: Por eso mismo, el filtro no tiene que aplicarse cuando invocas al servlet del login. El proceso sería: llamar al servlet del login (no pasa por filtro), el login añade el usuario a la sesión, del login se va, por ejemplo, al menú de la aplicación [/menu] que si pasa por filtro y valida al usuario.

Comment: vale ahora te he entendido, muchas gracias